# Display gif on hover for resizable image map

Tags: jquery, html, css, gif, imagemap

I'm working on my personal website, and my concept is that the homepage is a responsive image map which is a photo of a surface of a desk. The items on the desk represent projects, and when you mouse over these objects, quick animated gifs show that interact with the objects (like if it's a cup of coffee, a fish jumps out or something like that).

I have a responsive image map working with this JQuery plugin: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer

What I need now is to get a gif to show up in the  of the imagemap hotspot on mousein (or mouseover), and to go away on mouseout. It needs to resize with the .

My image map code is pretty standard and I've attached it at the end of this post.

Can anyone think of a way to get the gifs to show up where I want AND resize properly with the browser window? Do you think I have to go and mess with the plugin code myself to get the effect I want? Thank you in advance for your help!

```
    <div class="map">
        <img src="img/flatlay_sample.jpg" class="bg" id="bestmap" alt="image map" usemap="#image_map" width="1500" height="1101" orgWidth="1500" orgHeight="1101">

        <map name="image_map" id="bestmap"> 

            <area id="phone" alt="" title="phone" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="869,356,983,270,1190,518,1072,617,958,484" style="outline-color:red;" target="_self"     />
            <area id="coffee" alt="" title="coffee" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="370,604,408,540,433,611,508,659,521,755,461,835,335,837,285,771,297,660" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />

        </map> 

    </div>
```

Comment: could you post all your html css code with url image links ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using only html and css + jquery or javascript the plugin would make it more complicated,

see this example using only html+css

---

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin-top:10%;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9;
 }
.coffe , .cup {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.cup:before {
   position:absolute;
   
   width:150px;
   height:150%;
   background-image:url('https://www.amazing-animations.com/animations/fish54.gif');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   z-index:10;
   top:-80px;
   left:50%;
   transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.cup:hover:before{
   content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="coffe">
<div class="cup"><img src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/midle/Coffee_Cup_PNG_Clipart-401.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's awesome! here's my question though- do you think it would work with the jquery plugin when the window size changes and the image map proportionally shrinks? because the animation needs to move with the image map AND resize proportionally.

Comment: Yes in deed, you just need some responsive design knowledge